# What is the text CSS from Photoshop text properties

Tags: css, fonts, photoshop

What is the CSS that must be created to match (exactly) the style given in the text properties in Photoshop ?

Photoshop has four basic text properties:

[image]

1. **font-family**. The CSS for this is `font-family: name;`
2. ?
3. **font-size**. The CSS for this is `font-family: 0px;`
4. ?

But how can we set the style for the 2 and 3 properties ?

---

Here is what the options for those properties are:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert letter-tracking value set in Photoshop to equivalent letter-spacing in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509752/convert-letter-tracking-value-set-in-photoshop-to-equivalent-letter-spacing-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You aren't going to match them exactly.**

2.) Different combos of [`font-style`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-style), [`font-weight`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight), and [`letter-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing) will recreate many of the options.

4.) Aliasing [varies across browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864742/how-to-apply-font-anti-alias-effects-in-css) and doesn't have a "standard." That being said, [`font-smoothing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth) and especially [`text-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow) will get you pretty close. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17886204/2456258) has some good examples.

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cfalk/a14gqyje/)

Comment: What format does Photoshop follows ? I mean why don't they use standard CSS properties, and use their own ?.
I'm gonna keep searching for a table that tells me like: 'for Sharp use this style..., for Crisp use this style... for Condensed use this style....'.